# Pygame 2,7 Collision To 3,3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

I have recently made a game in python 2.7.6 with pygame and I am now converting all of the syntax and code to work with python 3.3.3. But I am having an issue with collision. Before I converted the collisions worked flawlessly, but in 3.3.3 all the collisions completely messed up. Here is my current code for the player, zombie and boss collisions:

```
def player_move(self):
    # Line start
    self.point = self.player.rect.x + 30, self.player.rect.y + 30
    # add gravity
    self.player.do_jump()

    # simulate gravity
    self.player.on_ground = False
    if not self.player.on_ground and not self.player.jumping:
        self.player.velY = 4

    if self.player.rect.y >= 680:
        self.player.lives -= 1
        self.player.rect.x = 320
        self.player.rect.y = 320

    # Drops
    for drop in self.gameDrops:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.player, drop):
            if type(drop) == HealthDrop:
                self.player.health += 50
                self.gameDrops.remove(drop)
            elif type(drop) == SuperHealthDrop:
                self.player.health += 1000
                self.gameDrops.remove(drop)
            elif type(drop) == TriBullets:
                self.player.power = POWER_TRIBULLETS
                self.gameDrops.remove(drop)
            elif type(drop) == ShieldDrop:
                self.player.power = POWER_SHIELD
                self.gameDrops.remove(drop)

    if self.player.score >= self.next_level_score:
        self.game_state = STATE_VICTORY
        self.player.score = 0
        self.zombieskilled = 0
        self.alivetime = 0
        self.lives = 3
        self.health = 200
        self.player.rect.x = 320
        self.player.rect.y = 320
        for zombie in self.zombies:
            zombie.rect.x = random.randint(0, 1280)
            zombie.rect.y = random.randint(0, 100)

    # Health
    for m in self.meteors:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.player, m):
            if self.player.power == POWER_SHIELD:
                self.player.health -= 25
            else:
                self.player.health -= 50

    for zombie in self.zombies:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.player, zombie):
            if self.player.power == POWER_SHIELD:
                self.player.health -= 1
            else:
                self.player.health -= 5

    for boss in self.bosses:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.player, boss):
            if self.player.power == POWER_SHIELD:
                self.player.health -= 50
            else:
                self.player.health -= 50

    # check if we die
    if self.player.health <= 0:
        self.player.power = POWER_NONE
        self.player.lives -= 1
        self.player.rect.x = 320
        self.player.rect.y = 320
        self.player.health = 200

    if self.player.lives <= 0:
        self.player.lives += 3
        self.player.score = 0
        self.targetscore = 100
        self.player.rect.x = 320
        self.player.rect.y = 320
        self.game_state = STATE_GAMEOVER
        for zombie in self.zombies:
            zombie.rect.x = random.randint(0, 1280)
            zombie.rect.y = random.randint(0, 100)

    # move player and check for collision at the same time
    self.player.rect.x += self.player.velX
    self.check_collision(self.player, self.player.velX, 0)
    self.player.rect.y += self.player.velY
    self.check_collision(self.player, 0, self.player.velY)

def zombie_move(self, zombie_sprite):
    # add gravity
    zombie_sprite.do_jump()
    percentage = random.randint(0, 100)

    # simualte gravity
    zombie_sprite.on_ground = False
    if not zombie_sprite.on_ground and not zombie_sprite.jumping:
        zombie_sprite.velY = 8

    if zombie_sprite.jumping:
        zombie_sprite.velX = 0

    for zombie in self.zombies:
        if zombie.rect.y >= 680:
            self.zombies.remove(zombie)

    dx = zombie_sprite.rect.x - self.player.rect.x
    if dx > 20 and not zombie_sprite.jumping:
        zombie_sprite.velX = -5
    elif dx < 20 and not zombie_sprite.jumping:
        zombie_sprite.velX = +5

    # Zombie damage
    for zombie in self.zombies:
        for m in self.meteors:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(m, zombie):
                zombie.health -= 10                
                if zombie.health <= 0:
                    if (percentage >= 0) and (percentage < 40):
                        self.gameDrops.append(HealthDrop(zombie.rect.x + 10, zombie.rect.y + 30))
                    elif (percentage >= 0) and (percentage < 5):
                        self.gameDrops.append(SuperHealthDrop(zombie.rect.x + 20, zombie.rect.y + 30))
                    elif (percentage >= 1) and (percentage < 20):
                        self.gameDrops.append(TriBullets(zombie.rect.x + 30, zombie.rect.y + 30, self.player.direction))
                    elif (percentage >= 1) and (percentage < 50):
                        self.gameDrops.append(ShieldDrop(zombie.rect.x + 40, zombie.rect.y + 30))
                    self.zombieskilled += 0
                    self.player.score += 0
                    self.meteors.remove(m)
                break

    for zombie in self.zombies:
        for b in self.bullets:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(b, zombie):
                #The same bullet cannot be used to kill
                #multiple zombies and as the bullet was 
                #no longer in Bullet.List error was raised
                zombie.health -= 10                
                self.bullets.remove(b)
                if zombie.health <= 0:
                    if (percentage >= 0) and (percentage < 40):
                        self.gameDrops.append(HealthDrop(zombie.rect.x + 10, zombie.rect.y + 30))
                    elif (percentage >= 0) and (percentage < 5):
                        self.gameDrops.append(SuperHealthDrop(zombie.rect.x + 20, zombie.rect.y + 30))
                    elif (percentage >= 1) and (percentage < 20):
                        self.gameDrops.append(TriBullets(zombie.rect.x + 30, zombie.rect.y + 30, self.player.direction))
                    elif (percentage >= 1) and (percentage < 50):
                        self.gameDrops.append(ShieldDrop(zombie.rect.x + 40, zombie.rect.y + 30))
                    self.zombieskilled += 1
                    self.player.score += 10
                    self.total_score += 10
                    self.zombies.remove(zombie)
                break

    # move zombie and check for collision
    zombie_sprite.rect.x += zombie_sprite.velX
    self.check_collision(zombie_sprite, zombie_sprite.velX, 0)
    zombie_sprite.rect.y += zombie_sprite.velY
    self.check_collision(zombie_sprite, 0, zombie_sprite.velY)

def boss_move(self, boss_sprite):
    # add gravity
    boss_sprite.do_jump()
    percentage = random.randint(0, 100)

    # simualte gravity
    boss_sprite.on_ground = False
    if not boss_sprite.on_ground and not boss_sprite.jumping:
        boss_sprite.velY = 8

    if boss_sprite.jumping:
        boss_sprite.velX = 0

    for boss in self.bosses:
        if boss.rect.y >= 620:
            self.bosses.remove(boss)

    dx = boss_sprite.rect.x - self.player.rect.x
    if dx > 20 and not boss_sprite.jumping:
        boss_sprite.velX = -5
    elif dx < 20 and not boss_sprite.jumping:
        boss_sprite.velX = +5

    # Zombie damage
    for boss in self.bosses:
        for m in self.meteors:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(m, boss):
                boss.health -= 0                
                if boss.health <= 0:
                    if (percentage >= 0) and (percentage < 40):
                        self.gameDrops.append(HealthDrop(boss.rect.x + 10, boss.rect.y + 30))
                    elif (percentage >= 0) and (percentage < 5):
                        self.gameDrops.append(SuperHealthDrop(boss.rect.x + 20, boss.rect.y + 30))
                    elif (percentage >= 1) and (percentage < 20):
                        self.gameDrops.append(TriBullets(boss.rect.x + 30, boss.rect.y + 30, self.player.direction))
                    elif (percentage >= 1) and (percentage < 50):
                        self.gameDrops.append(ShieldDrop(boss.rect.x + 40, boss.rect.y + 30))
                    self.zombieskilled += 0
                    self.player.score += 0
                    self.meteors.remove(m)
                break

    for boss in self.bosses:
        for b in self.bullets:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(b, boss):
                #The same bullet cannot be used to kill
                #multiple bosses and as the bullet was 
                #no longer in Bullet.List error was raised
                boss.health -= 5                
                self.bullets.remove(b)
                if boss.health <= 0:
                    if (percentage >= 0) and (percentage < 50):
                        self.gameDrops.append(SuperHealthDrop(boss.rect.x + 90, boss.rect.y + 90))
                    elif (percentage >= 0) and (percentage < 50):
                        self.gameDrops.append(TriBullets(boss.rect.x + 90, boss.rect.y + 90, self.player.direction))
                    self.zombieskilled += 1
                    self.player.score += 50
                    self.total_score += 50
                    self.bosses.remove(boss)
                break

    # move boss and check for collision
    boss_sprite.rect.x += boss_sprite.velX
    self.check_collision(boss_sprite, boss_sprite.velX, 0)
    boss_sprite.rect.y += boss_sprite.velY
    self.check_collision(boss_sprite, 0, boss_sprite.velY)

def check_collision(self, sprite, x_vel, y_vel):
    # for every tile in Background.levelStructure, check for collision
    for block in self.moon.get_surrounding_blocks(sprite):
        if block is not None:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite, block):
                # we've collided! now we must move the collided sprite a step back
                if x_vel < 0:
                    sprite.rect.x = block.rect.x + block.rect.w

                    if type(sprite) is Zombie:
                        # the sprite is a zombie, let's make it jump
                        if not sprite.jumping:
                            sprite.jumping = True
                            sprite.on_ground = False
                        else:
                            sprite.jumping = False
                            sprite.on_ground = True

                if x_vel > 0:
                    sprite.rect.x = block.rect.x - sprite.rect.w

                    if type(sprite) is Zombie:
                        # the sprite is a zombie, let's make it jump
                        if not sprite.jumping:
                            sprite.jumping = True
                            sprite.on_ground = False
                        else:
                            sprite.jumping = False
                            sprite.on_ground = True

                if y_vel < 0:
                    sprite.rect.y = block.rect.y + block.rect.h

                if y_vel > 0 and not sprite.on_ground:
                    sprite.on_ground = True
                    sprite.rect.y = block.rect.y - sprite.rect.h
```

That is all of the code from the player, zombie and boss for them you collide and there functions so they know to collide. I have called the collision function too as you can see in the code for all three. I am really annoyed at this because I am not sure whether it is to do with syntax or what. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What does all messed up mean? How do I run your code?

Comment: None of the collisions are working..

Comment: have you done anything to check why they are not working? Added print statements, to see why some code is run and not the other?

Comment: I have tried but can't see anything. I have played around with collide_rect but still no luck at all.

Comment: Without a [ssce](http://sscce.org/) i'm afraid this is a guessing game.

Comment: I just did a quick test but something strange happens. When the code is executed in the Python IDLE then the collisions dont work. If it is ran via double clicking on the code then it works. The collisions will only not work if it is ran from any IDE, only double clicking. So what is wrong here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46787/discussion-between-bartlomiej-lewandowski-and-ghostfrag1)

Comment: I managed to notice something earlier. I have a test game too testing some different things with the same collision setup and the collisions on that work with 3.3.3 and 2.7.6. If necessary I can show required code to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the fix! In my levelstructure file to randomly generate the terrain and position. In my generation class I had a get_surrounding_blocks as you can see in def check_collision. In that surrounding_blocks I had:

```
def get_surrounding_blocks(self, sprite):
    # calculate the grid position of the sprite
    sprite_x = sprite.rect.x / 64
    sprite_y = sprite.rect.y / 64
```

And in python 2.7.6 one division sign (/) will give you an integer but in python 3.3.3 you must do // to get an integer otherwise you may get a float with just one /.